# How to add alert messages in Django LoginRequiredMixin

Tags: django, django-login, django-messages

So i am using `LoginRequiredMixin` in Django for some of my feature that require users to logged in. but since i am using class based views and there's no request i don't know how to  add `django.contrib.messages` in my view and template. Is there a way to add this messages feature while using class based views ?

Answer (score 0):

You can access the request as follows:

```
class MyClassBasedView(LoginRequiredMixin, generics.DetailView):
    def get_object(self, *args, **kwargs):
        request = self.request
        return super(MyClassBasedView, self).get_object()
```